# Http requests fails only while releasing Android APK

Tags: android, cordova, http, ionic-framework, apk

I'm struggling in making my app work on Android APK release, the only scenario it fails is at generating and signing the apk. All http requests doesn't work. (The server is running under SSL)

All Scenarios I've tried already:

- `ionic serve` -> Works fine.
- `ionic cordova run android --device` -> Works fine.
- Works on emulators as well.

Also works fine generating the iOS build:

- `ionic cordova build ios`.
- On Xcode, running build targeting a real device.
- On Xcode, archiving and uploading it to Itunesconnect then downloading it from AppStore once it's accepted by Apple.

So, the only case it doesn't work is when I try to generate it's apk through `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` and signing it.

Google Play also accepts the new APK, so there's no problem with the package sign at all.

Since it works on iOS and running directly on android device, it isn't a CORS or HTTPS certificate problem.

The code:

snippet of login.ts:

```
this.userService.loginUser(this.user).then(
            (data) => {
                let response = data.json();
                loading.dismiss().then(loadData => {
                    if (response.access_token) {
                        this.global.access_token = response.access_token;
                        this.getUserData();
                    }
                });
            }, err => {
                let error = err.json();
                loading.dismiss().then(response => {
                    if (error.message) {
                        this.showToast(error.message, 3000, 'bottom');
                    }
                });
            }
        );
```

userService.loginUser method:

```
loginUser(data) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.append('auth-token', '*');

    return this.abs.post('/authenticateMobile',
        {
            login_ds_email: data.email,
            login_ds_password: data.pass
        }, headers);
}
```

Where `abs` is:

```
constructor(http) {
    this.abs = new ApiService(http);
}
```

ApiService.post method:

```
public post(api, params, header): any {
    if (!header) {
        header = this.getHeaders();
    }
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: header});
    let url = this.global.urlGlobal + api;
    return this.http.post(url, params, options).toPromise();
}
```

The App gets stuck when I fire "login" button and the request is made. There's no exception thrown by the server, so the loading screen is shown forever.

I've running out of solutions for this and I hope you guys can help me out.

Ionic info:

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 6.4.0
Gulp CLI         : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-gulp          : 1.0.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.0.0 ios 4.3.1
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.0.1

System:

Node       : v7.8.0
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
ios-deploy : 1.9.0
ios-sim    : 5.0.6
npm        : 5.0.3
```

Comment: The error function is NOT firing - resulting in a toast message at bottom?

Comment: Error function not even being fired, no toast shown as well. It actually was a certificate issue that caused the whole app to stop working.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had this exact same issue some time ago. In my case the problem was an invalid certificate. The certificate looked fine to me in the browser (chrome even showed the green lock), on iOS and while testing on Android. But I had android-users complain it wasn't working for them.

After hours of researching it turned out that requests to websites with invalid certificates just get silently dropped, which means there is no feedback whatsoever. No errors, nothing. (If I remember correctly, the js code just stopped executing without returning or executing any callbacks.) This happens ONLY when building in release mode.

A workaround is described here:

http://ivancevich.me/articles/ignoring-invalid-ssl-certificates-on-cordova-android-ios/

The best way to handle it would be to pin the certificate in your app.

Comment: It was indeed a Certificate issue, thank you for the tip about the workaround!

Comment: Very less info about these kind of issues.. you saved my day.. Thanks..

Comment: Man, you saved my life -_-

Comment: how did you verify that this is an invalid certificate? I have the same problem but the site certificate works correctly on browsers and the ssl check tells me that the certificate is valid. But I have seen that the problem occurs only on android devices <5.1

Comment: @Francesco I also have the same issue where request does not work below Android 5. Did you find any solution for the issue ?? And also I did an SSL check which looks fine.

Comment: @ShashankHS yes I've found a solution, in my case the problem was an intermediate certificate configuration error. You can check on this article https://www.digicert.com/util/repair-intermediate-ssl-certificate-errors-using-digicert-utility-for-microsoft-servers.htm and  this https://medium.com/@itzfitz/how-to-fix-comodo-certificate-not-trusted-on-android-devices-afa405a35310

Answer (score 7):

My issue was incomplete SSL chain, solve it by reconfiguring nginx to have the entire chain of SSL certificates as described here:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains

Answer (score 5):

My problem was with SSL as well. If you get an "A+" rating from this website, it should work. My original grade was "B".
 https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest

You can use this site to correct it. 
https://whatsmychaincert.com/

Comment: This was the issue and whatsmychaincert.com fixed it. Thank you!